# eventlistener function not firing, can't work out why

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

```
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const ingredients = document.getElementById("ingredients");
const recipe = document.getElementById("recipe");
const ginger = document.getElementById("ging");
const pineapple = document.getElementById("pine");
const carrot = document.getElementById("carr");
const toffee = document.getElementById("toff");
const icedbun = document.getElementById("iced");
const card = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

ging = {
    name: "Sticky Ginger Cake",
    ingredients: "<br> <ol><li>50g/20oz Butter</li><li>200g/8oz Stoned dates</li><li>300g/10oz Dark muscado sugar</li><li>2 eggs</li><li>50g/2oz Root ginger grated (2tsp)</li><li>Grated zest of a lemon</li><li>200g/8oz SR Flour</li><li>1 Bramley apple (9oz) peeled and chopped</li></ol>",
    recipe: "<ul><li> Butter and line a 20cm round cake tin</li><li>Put fdates in bowl and cover with boiling water</li><li>Heat butter in a pan and stir in the sugar. Allow to cool slightly</li><li>Beat in the eggs, ginger and lemon zest, then drain the dates, add to pan and mix well</li>                   <li>Stir in the flour then apples</li>                  <li>Spoon into cake tin, put cake on baking tray to stop the base browning too much.</li>                   <li>cook on gas 4/160 deg for 1 1/2 hours. If not cooked, cover with foil and cook for 15-30 mins more.</li>                   <li>Allow to cool in tin, then melt white chocolate drizzle over cake.</li></ul>"
}

carr = {
    name: "Carrot Cake",
    ingredients: "<ol><li>9oz SR flour</li><li>2 tsp Cinnamon</li><li>8oz Brown sugar - soft or demerara</li><li>4oz Coconut</li><li>6 oz Sultanas</li><li>2 eggs</li><li>1/2 tsp Vanilla</li><li>4oz Butter/Margerine</li><li>4oz Veg oil</li><li>4oz Grated carrots</li></ol>",
    recipe : "<ul><li>Preheat oven 160 deg/gas 4</li><li>Mix all dry ingredients together</li><li>Beat the eggs, vanilla, butter/margerine, and veg oil together</li><li>Add dry ingredients</li><li>Add grated carrots</li><li>Put in tin and sprinkle with demerara sugar</li><li>Cook for 1 to 1 1/2 hours</li></ul>"
}

pine = {
    name: "Pineapple Cake",
    ingredients: "<ol><li>1/2 Cup of butter, softened</li><li>1 Cup or sugar</li><li>1/4 tsp Sale</li><li>1/4 tsp Bicarbonate of soda</li><li>2 eggs</li><li>1 1/2 Cups of flour</li><li>1/4 Cup of crushed pineapple, well drained</li></ol>",
    recipe : "<ul><li>Preheat oven to gas 4</li><li>Mix together butter, sugar and eggs in a large bowl.</li><li>Beat in flour, bicarbonate of soda and salt.</li><li>Stir in pineapple.</li><li>Spread into a 9x9 square tin for bars, or into cupcake shells.</li><li>Cook gas 4 for 40/45 mins.</li><li>Drizzle with lemon icing.</li></ul>"
}

iced = {
    name: "Iced Cream Buns",
    ingredients: "<ol><li>2 tsp or 17g Pack dried yeast</li><li>4 floz Warm water</li><li>2 1/2 oz Sugar</li><li>4 floz Warm milk</li><li>2 1/2 oz Butter melted (weight first)</li><li>1 tsp Salt</li><li>1 Egg, slightly beaten</li><li>20 oz Bread flour</li></ol>",
    recipe : "<ul><li>Put flour in stand mixer bowl with yeast on one side, salt on the other</li><li>Mix together milk, egg, melted butter and 3 oz of warm water</li><li>Add sugar to flour and yeast then mix for a few seconds</li><li>Add the liquid - might need a litle more warm water</li><li>Put mixer on for 3 minutes, adding a little more water if needed</li><li>Put in large greased bowl and leave to double in size</li><li>Cut dough into about 15 pieces and place onto a greased baking tray then leave to double in size</li><li>Cook in preheated oven, 180 deg/Gas 4 for 20 minsm then add plain iced glaze on top</li></ul>"
}

toff = {
    name: "Sticky Toffee Pudding",
    ingredients: "<ol><li>225g Dates</li><li>175ml Boiling water</li><li>1tsp Vanilla</li><li>1 tsp Bi carbonate of soda</li><li>175g S.R Flour</li><li>2 Eggs</li><li>85g Butter</li><li>100ml Milk</li><li>140g demorara sugar</li></ol><p>Toffee Sauce:</p><ol><li>175kg Dark brown sugar</li><li>50g Butter</li><li>225ml Double cream</li><li>1 tbsp Black treacle</li></ol>",
    recipe : "<ul><li>Soak dates in boiling water.</li><li>Mix flour and Bicarbonate of soda.</li><li>Beat eggs.</li><li>Beat butter and sugar until creamy, then add eggs a little bit at a time.</li><li>stir in treacle then fold in 1/3 of the flour, 1/2 the milk, then repeat until used.</li><li>Stir in soaked dates *note* may look curdled (it isn't)</li><li>Spoon into mini pudding basins.</li><li>Cook gas 4 for 20 - 25 mins.</li></ul><p>Sauce:</p><ul><li>Put butter and sugar in a pan with 1/2 the cream and bring it to boil</li><li>Stir until sugar has dissolved, then stir in treacle and bubble for a few minutes.</li><li>Take off heat and beat in rest of cream.</li></ul>"
}

document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        this.classList.remove("fader");
    });
})

document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.classList.add("fader");
    });
})


function recipecard(obj) {
    name.innerHTML = obj.name;
    ingredients.innerHTML = obj.ingredients; 
    recipe.innerHTML = obj.recipe;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        obj = this.id.toString()
        recipecard(obj)
    });
})
```

in the last function -

```
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        obj = this.id.toString()
        recipecard(obj)
    });
})
```

obj returns the ID name which corresponds to the object name that contains the information to feed the recipecard() function, yet the HTML returns Undefined still. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

I've also tried straight up using

```
recipecard(this.id)
```

Which also returns undefined. I'm relatively new to coding so I'm sure I must be overlooking something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.id` is a string (so no need for `.toString()` on it). You're passing that string to `recipecard`, which is then using it as though it were the object referred to by the variable with that name. It isn't, though, it's just a string. See the linked question's answers for approaches you can take to look up an object based on a name (short version: use an object (perhaps `const recipes = {/*...*/};`  with a property for each object, and then look up the object (`const recipe = recipes[id];`).

Comment: Side note: That code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare your variables. Not declaring them, in loose mode, makes them globals.

Comment: Final note: You've done **so much right** in that code. So much. I see at least three basic errors people always make that you didn't make. Nice one!

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/Lsvp6wd1/1/

Comment: Thank you so much TJ. Not only was that a great answer but I learnt a hell of a lot more than I asked, I really appreciate the time you spent getting back to me.